# Deploying front end and back end at the same time with Heroku Pipelines

Tags: heroku, heroku-pipelines

I'm considering separating the front end and back end of my application into two separate self contained apps that would end up as separate apps in Heroku. I'm using Heroku pipelines/flow to manage deployments and so far, the "Promote to Production" button was sort-of atomic.

With front and back end separate, most likely I would have to put the front end in maintenance mode, deploy back end, once it works, deploy front end, and once that works remove from maintenance mode. It's no longer nice and atomic. Is there any way to have this process automated so whoever is deploying doesn't need to remember to do it correctly?

I know technically you can develop so that updates to one or the other keep the system working, but being backwards or forwards compatible like that introduces more work than we can cope with at the moment.

Comment: Interesting question, I've pondered the same issue. To me it seems that to treat them as separate apps is to inherently suggest that they're de-coupled (which has pros and cons). We run a LoopBack API and an Angular front-end that exist as 2 separate apps. If we push any changes to the API that would break the Angular front-end or any other consumers, we obviously have to plan a maintenance period as you've suggested (which in reality may only be a few minutes). If they're not breaking, we deploy the API's pipeline normally.